# Ionic 2 WP-REST API post request 401 error with headers set for basic authentication

Tags: http, angular, ionic2, basic-authentication, wp-api

I am developing a simple application to create a post in Wordpress through wp-rest api. Everything(creating, updating deleting posts) works fine on postman. I  can even fetch posts  using same api in my application. but when I try to create a posts it shows 401 Unauthorised error in console.
heres is my code for request.

```
//create post by api
createPost(title,content){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic '+btoa('tarun:iamtarun'));
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return this.http.post(this.postUrl+'?title='+title+'&content='+content , {
        headers:headers 
    })
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of http `post` request is

`post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;`

So the request should be,

```
return this.http.post(this.postUrl+'?title='+title+'&content='+content ,{}, { headers:headers })
```

Where the body is an empty object.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Spot on. Working like charm now.

Comment: Accept it as answer if it helped.